# less hacky way of making a div wider than its container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

trying to tidy up a blog im designing and need a more stable way of doing this.

Currently my layout is e.g.

```
<div id="blog">
    <div id="blogtext">
    IMAGES AND TEXT BLAH
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a padding on the blogtext div of 5% so that there is some nice white space around the blog content. However, i want the images to be full width of the div.

The blog data is all taken from one database field and then converted to HTML (currently saved as BBCODE) and then it is echoed out as one single variable e.g. $text

I have made a jsfiddle of what i currently do. I set the image tag to be wider than the containing div and then position it using a minus margin. But this just seems a bit hacky to me. And once moving around screen res's i can imagine the results differing slightly.

Heres the fiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/AwneN/

Any better suggestions for this or should i just stick with it?

Comment: Why does the image have to be inside the content tag? If you make a separate container for the text and the image, you wouldn't have to try and make a child container larger than the parent container, right?

Comment: the content is user submitted in the style of a forum, where there will be text, an images, some more text etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why that means you can't have them in separate containers... Example - every bit of text content in p tags, which then allows you to separate your styling rules between the p tags and img tags.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with what you did, but you could also do something like:

```
* { box-sizing: Border-box; } //http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

#content * {
    padding: 5%;
}

#content #image {
    margin-top: 5%;
    height: 200px;
    padding:0; //Reset padding for images
    background-color: #fefefe;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AwneN/

You might want to look at the `box-sizing` style since you're working with percentages.

Comment: Have you tested this ? ... doesn't work the text isn't in another tag.Also your fiddle is exactly the same of the OP question